# Issue with Django URLs on apache production server

Tags: django, apache, url, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I have a Django site and I have set up a test server for it. Now, the test server is being used for something else (php) also and I have configured it as aliases in virtual host config for Apache.

Now the problem is this:
When I open it as: http://x.x.x.x/djangoSite/
the WSGI triggers Django and site loads perfectly. But still all the anchor tags point to http://x.x.x.x/viewFunction/ and not http://x.x.x.x/djangoSite/viewFunction/  and hence I get a 404 every time...

Is there a way to tell Django that the base URL for the site is not the domain (public IP) but instead domain/djangoSite/  from where the WSGI alias starts...

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code, but you are probably hard-coding the URLs in your templates. Don't do this: you should always use the `{% url %}` tag to calculate them dynamically. When you do this, Django will automatically apply the base path (passed as the SCRIPT_NAME parameter in the WSGI environment) and all will be well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to set this SCRIPT_NAME manually in WSGI loader file as:
os.environ["SITE_NAME"] = '/djangoSite' 
but it does not seem to do anything... Can't this be set manually ..? Basically, I have 20 odd template files with a bunch of links. So, is there a way around other than having to edit every single link in the template files..?

Comment: Well, firstly it's SCRIPT_NAME not SITE_NAME - but there's no point setting it manually, WSGI does it for you. But the other issue is that it only works in conjunction with the `{% url %}` tag. A hard-coded link like `<a href="/viewFunction">` will *always* point to the root - that's just the way HTML works. An alternative might be to write some middleware that parses your rendered templates and fixes the URL, but that's horrible and just moves the work from a one-off change to something that has to run every time a page is viewed.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Got the concept now... I think will have to edit the links then... No way out !
Thanks for the insight !